# Check User is member of Azure AD Group

Tags: azure, active-directory, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to Azure. I have published my MVC 5 website to Azure. I have a list of group names and their objectid in c# dictionary. The AD groups are created in Azure AD Directory. I am trying to find whether the logged in user is member of a Azure AD Group. For some reason I am not successful. I am getting NUllreferenceException when I use `GraphConnection.IsMemberOf()` function. Would be great if you anyone could help me solve this.

Here is my code

```
try
            {
                var userObjectId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
                var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, loginUrl, tenant));
                var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                var result = authContext.AcquireToken(graphResourceId, credential);

                var clientRequestId = Guid.NewGuid();
                var graphSettings = new GraphSettings
                {
                    ApiVersion = GraphConfiguration.GraphApiVersion
                };
                var graphConnection = new GraphConnection(result.AccessToken, clientRequestId, graphSettings);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.adGroupObjectId))
                {
                    var groups = graphConnection.List<Group>(null, null);

                    if (groups != null && groups.Results != null)
                    {
                        var group = groups.Results.SingleOrDefault(r => r.DisplayName == adGroup);
                        if (group != null)
                            adGroupObjectId = group.ObjectId;
                    }
                }
                if (adGroupObjectId != null)
                    inGroup = graphConnection.IsMemberOf(adGroupObjectId, userObjectId);

                return inGroup;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                var message = string.Format("Unable to authorize AD user: {0} against group: {1}", ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.Name, adGroup);
                throw new Exception(message, ex);                
            }
```

Comment: I am getting error for all methods i try with graphConnection. eg: graphConnection.Get<User>(userObjectId);

Answer (score -1):

Akhil, we have recently turned on the Application Roles and Groups Claim features in Azure AD. Depending on your scenario one of these should be the right fit.

Get a quick overview here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2014/12/18/azure-active-directory-now-with-group-claims-and-application-roles.aspx

Deep dive post and video on app roles feature is here: http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/roles-based-access-control-in-cloud-applications-using-azure-ad/

Deep dive post and video on groups claim feature is here: http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/authorization-cloud-applications-using-ad-groups/

Hope that helps.

Comment: None of the links works at the moment, please fix this or post the relevant information directly into the post.